# BLE device characteristic says it read-only, but log says otherwise

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have no previous experience with bluetooth connections or anything related to bluetooth, but I'm trying to hack my [smartband](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Activity-Monitor-Smartband-Wrist-Pulse-Meter-Smart-Band-F1-Wristband-Pedometer-Bluetooth-Step-Counter-Bracelet-For/32811388762.html) to provide more meaningful notifications from my Android device. 
I'm using Xamarin and [Plugin.BLE](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le) library I installed through Nuget to write the code to do so.

This is what I found about it using nRF Connect:

[image]

And I was able to capture this log:
[image: LogFile]

This displays "(Whatsapp icon) WhatsappW.." on the smartband screen.

As I understand, the app is sending a write command to a read-only property (uuid:2A04).

But when I try to send a write myself (using the CharacteristBase.WriteBytes provided by the Plugin.BLE library) it throws an exception, I'm aware that this validation is done by the library itself and I could download the code and change this validation, but I wonder if this the right way to it and if I'm reading the log correctly.

Is there an explanation to this or am I reading the log wrongly?

Either way, thanks in advance.

Comment: The connection parameters for a BLE connection is a set of parameters that determine when and how the Central and a Peripheral in a link transmits data. It contains the Connection interval, the Slave latency and the Connection supervision timeout. 
This has nothing to do with writing to the characteristic you want to write to.

Comment: I see, is there a way to found out which characteristic it's writing into? Or a way to mimic this message?

Comment: If you want any help on this matter, we need to know from what platform you write your code  and the programming language you use(e.g.windows 10 c#) and the platform you target(e.g. Android 7.1-API25).
Normal practice is:
Scan for devices, select and connect to your device, get all services, get all characteristics of these services and find out by trying to write to all the writable characteristics and see what happens.

Comment: Sure:
C# with Xamarin on a Windows 10. API level is Android 7.0 - API24.

Also I'm using that library I mentioned, Plugin.BLE.

I'll try to send the same value from the log to every writable property to see if it works.

Comment: You will have to edit your question and add the code you have so far.
You are using CharacteristBase.WriteBytes and that makes no sense to me.
It has to be something like:

 await characteristic.WriteAsync(tosend).ConfigureAwait(false);

where tosend is a byte array, characteristic is the characteristic to write to and ConfigureAwait(false) is to make sure it is executed on the main thread.